# Progress bar not showing when using join() on thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

```
Private static ProgressDialog loading;

public void downloadData(){
    Thread t = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
          //download stuff
        }
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    };
    t.start();
    try{
        t.join();
    }catch(InterruptedException ignore){}
}

private Handler handler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        loading.dismiss();
    }
};
```

When I call donloadData without using `t.join()` it displays the ProgressDialog.

However, when using `t.join()`, the t thread seems to execute correctly but the `ProgressDialog` does not show.

Why is the `ProgressDialog` not showing?

Any suggestions on what to change so that I can use `t.join()` and display the `ProgressDialog`?

Comment: Why are you doing this? `t.start()` followed by `t.join()` is functionally identical to `t.run()` except for wasting another thread stack and several context switches.

Comment: The ProgressDialog is not showing because you are using join().  So, if you want to show the ProgressDialog, do not use join().  Why do you want to use join() straight after start()?  You may as well just forget the thread completely and just call the download stuff.

Comment: The whole point of threads is that your program can do two things at the same time.  If the first thread is just going to sit and wait for the second one, there's no point creating the second thread; just do the work in the first one.

Comment: I think it's obvious I need to educate myself about threads

Answer (score 0):

the `t.join` method will block current thread util the `t thread` finish it's work.

try this:

```
Private static ProgressDialog loading;

public void downloadData(){
    Thread t = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
          //download stuff

         //edit: when finish down load and send dismiss message
         handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
        //handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    };

    //edit: before start make the dialog show
    loading.show();

    t.start();
    //edit: the join method is not necessary
    try{
        t.join();
    }catch(InterruptedException ignore){}
}

private Handler handler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        loading.dismiss();
    }
};
```

above code may be solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

join() is a call o'death.  If a thread blocks or gets stuck, calling join() on it ensures that the stuckness is efficiently extended to the calling thread.

If you can possibly get away with it, don't use join() at all.  Especially don't use it to wait for results from another thread by calling it straight after start().  Double-especially don't use it in a GUI event-handler.